How to remove a whole line in vscode using search and replace, only part of the line
I want to remove every line containing "albumname"
what I have
"ts": "2024-03-15T05:07:50.716Z",
"albumName": "Popular KPOP Best 15 Vol. 26"

what I want
"ts": "2024-03-15T05:07:50.716Z"

The problem is I can't put the whole line because what's after "albumname" is different every time, for example
one will be
"albumName": "Popular KPOP Best 15 Vol. 26"

another will be
"albumName": "LES (Speed Version)"

I have tried "albumname"\n, didn't work obviously.
Edit: I also want the comma at the end of the ts line removed.

Turn on "Use regular expression" (regex) and use .*\n to match the rest of the line.
"albumname".*\n


. means "any character".
* means "zero or more times".
\n will match LF or CRLF line endings

Remove comma from previous line
Strictly speaking, the comma isn't part of the 'line containing "albumname" ', but removing it seems to be required to result in valid JSON.
Now, since this is JSON, ideally you should be using a JSON parser, but the task is still possible with regex if the format is consistent, say like this:
[
{
"ts": "2024-03-15T05:07:50.716Z",
"albumName": "Popular KPOP Best 15 Vol. 26"
},
{
"ts": "2024-03-15T05:07:50.716Z",
"albumName": "LES (Speed Version)"
}
]

Then the pattern becomes:
,\n"albumname".*

Result:
[
{
"ts": "2024-03-15T05:07:50.716Z"
},
{
"ts": "2024-03-15T05:07:50.716Z"
}
]

Example using a JSON parser
Here's an example Python script that takes the same input and prints the same output as above:
import json

json_filename = 'test.json'  # <- Your filename here

with open(json_filename) as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for d in data:  # For each dict in the list
    d.pop('albumName')  # Remove "albumName" key-value pair

print(json.dumps(data, indent=0))  # Just prints, doesn't output to file


This worked thx, I just have one more problem. Theres a comma at the end on the line above(the "ts" line), and that needs to be removed

@Sea- Oh! That's not part of the line containing "albumname". This is JSON text, yeah? You should be using a JSON parser then, not find-and-replace. But it might still be possible if the format is consistent.

Yeah this is a json.

@Sea- Added. I'll see if I can write up a parser solution too.

@Sea- I added a Python example too, using a JSON parser

Have you tried using Ctrl+Shift+L on albumname (or Ctrl+D repeatedly) and then Shift+End to highlight the whole line(s) and then the Del key?
edit:
Regex is a much better option i.e. "albumname:".*/n

Well I could do that but theres thousands so that would take forever. Was hoping theres a more efficient way

Instead of pressing Ctrl+D repeatedly, just press Ctrl+Shift+L to invoke "Select All Occurrences of Find Match" (editor.action.selectHighlights)

Oh that is so much better. My answer is bad.

@JeevanGopinath By all means edit it in! Comments are for suggesting improvements after all :) I would have posted another answer if I wanted to :)
